# Control an Adorner's visibility using a Property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, adorner

Would it be possible for an Adorner to be hidden / displayed depending on the value of a property in a class ?

Should I use attached properties for this purpose ?

If so, how exactly can the Adorner's visibility be controlled; do I have to manually remove it / add it to the Adorner Layer within the Dependency Object's OnChanged event ?

This is just a very quick code representation of what I'm trying to do:

(**Note**: I'm not even sure if its the right way of doing things. I want the Adorner's visibility to be controlled by the value of a property that is modified by the code in my business model. The problem with Attached Properties is that its the control's responsibility to update the value of the property instead of the code in my business domain.)

```
public static class IsValidBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsValidProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsValid",
                                                                    typeof(bool),
                                                                    typeof(IsValidBehavior),
                                                                    new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsValidChanged));

    public static bool GetIsValid(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsValidProperty);
    }
    public static void SetIsValid(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsValidProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnIsValidChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement element = dependencyObject as UIElement;

        if (element == null)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
        {
            // Display the Adorner
        }
        else
        {
            // Hide the Adorner
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Added a quick code sample in the post. I just came up with it, but it should give an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if I right understood your question, in `WPF` you have 2 ways to do that, from code or from `XAML`. From code, you more or less already did, in XAML you can do  something like this, I think:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=MyVisibilityVariant, 
       Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}
```

In other words bind it to some property. My general suggestion: is use XAML whenever you can, considering a couple of variants:

- XAML declaration makes the software very scallable, but also more complex (consider your, or your group cappabilities, somehow doing the stuff in code behind is best, if not only solution available)
- Consider you deadlines, cause on XAML stuff implementing/debugging/fixing you will spend more time then on code.

**EDIT**

[Defining custom Adorder in order to be able to define it in XAML](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/adornedcontrol.aspx)

Comment: But can I bind the visibility of an Adorner in XAML..? Can an Adorner even be designed in XAML..? I was under the impression that we could only create / assign adorners in code ?

Comment: @Hussein: Sure you can, but you need to define a custom type. Adorner, at the end, is FrameworkElement, which you can extend in order to provide XAML support for your adorner user. Check out my edited post.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the link and report back. From what I understand, I won't even need to use attached properties.

Comment: I tested the code at the link you provided and it worked great. I'll analyze it and see if I should edit it. I believe it's possible to create a user control in XAML / Expression Blend and use that as the Adorner, correct ?

Comment: If you define it like in the article, yes.